# Find value within gridview column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I find if a specific value appears within any row in a gridview column? Something like:

```
  if (GridView1.Columns[1].Contains("Live"))
     {
      GridView1.Columns[2].Visible = true;
     }
```

Comment: Any idea why has this been down voted?

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted you but here are 2 Reasons why: Winter Bash gives you a hat if you downvote 5 Posts and maybe you could have provided more details. But i think it was the first one so you get +1 because i think the effort was sufficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to loop through each row and check the relevant cell, something like this:

```
bool found = false;
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
   TableCell cell = row.Cells[1];
   if(cell.Text.Contains("Live"))
   {
      found = true;
      break;
   }
}

if(found)
{
    GridView1.Columns[2].Visible = true;
}
```